# ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException while processing user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a program that uses a sentinal contolled do-while loop, that repeatedly asks the user for positive integers.

The loop should end when a negative value is entered by the user. After the loop completes, your program should print out the minimum, maximum, average, and count of the positive numbers that
were entered by the user.

However when I run the program, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at posNeg.main(posNeg.java:31)
```

I have searched for answers but none of them seem to be working.  Most just suggest removing the `=` from the `for (int i = 0; i <= (count); i++) {`.

Anyway, here is the full code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class posNeg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int num;
        int count = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("enter pos nums (or a neg num to quit): ");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            list.add(num);
            count++;
        } while (num >= 0);

        Iterator it = list.iterator();

        list.remove(list.get(count-1));

        Object max = Collections.max(list);
        Object min = Collections.min(list);

        System.out.print(list);

        int tot = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (count); i++) {
            Object piece = list.get(i);
            int piecenum = ((Number) piece).intValue();
            tot = tot + piecenum;
        }

        double avg;
        avg = tot/count;

        System.out.println("the max is "+max+". the min is "+min+". the avg is "+avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Most just suggest removing the ' = '"... Try it.

Comment: And what happened when you followed the suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

When you build your list, you increment count.

So after building `count==list.size()`.

After that you remove one item from the listbut don't change `count`.

So `count==list.size()-1`.

So your loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count-2; i++) {
```

because you have items from index `0` to `count-2`.

But instead of maintaining a count, you could simply do

```
for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (count); i++) {
```

At this point the list only has `count - 1` items, but you're looping `count + 1` times. For the sake of sanity you should decrement `count` after the call to `remove`, and then *also* change the loop to the more idiomatic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
```

Or, rather more simply:

```
for (Number number : list) {
    ...
}
```

This will only work after making `list` generic though:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

You should *really* be using generics for collections.

Answer (score 0):

Better do it this way....

```
for (int i = 0; i < (count); i++) {


 }
```

**Or**

Use the `For-Each` loop

```
for(Number n : list){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is with count, as others have noted.  I suggest using a conditional `break;` in your input loop to avoid adding the negative value to the list, and incrementing count. in the first place.  You will still need to replace `<=` with `<` whenever using a language with zero based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

try this `list.size` instead of count

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object piece = list.get(i);
            int piecenum = ((Number) piece).intValue();
            tot = tot + piecenum;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions,,,

```
    do{
        System.out.println("enter pos nums (or a neg num to quit): ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num >= 0)
           break;
        list.add(num);
    }while (true);
```

.. and for the next loop

```
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i : list ) {
        //do your stuff
    }
```

.. but you should really use a typed list

```
  List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>()
```

... or something like that